# Java Iterator as a class?

Tags: java, iterator

I am intrigued by something that looks obvoius, but it's not for me. We have a hashSet and Iterator:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
Iterator it = set.iterator();
```

I know, how iterator works, but there's something weird to me:

Iterator* it = set.iterator();**

* ok, wait. Iterator is an interface, not a class. So... ?
** ok, set is an object of class HashSet, and it implements interface Iterator, so ith has void interator() imlemented, nothing unusual.

But how can we create Iterator object from Iterator interface ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: That should read `Iterator<String> it = set.iterator();`

Comment: See [Programming to an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of `iterator()` method in `HashSet` returns an object that implements the `Iterator` interface. The object returned is an instance of some concrete class that conforms to the `Iterator` specification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Thanks, but how can we make Iterator it = ... We can make String, Integer - objects, but not interfaces.

Comment: `HashMap` returns an object of a concrete class implementing `Iterator`, however said class is hidden and/or anonymous. The 'user' of `.iterator()` shouldn't care either way.

Comment: FYI, found the class here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.KeyIterator

Answer (score 5):

First of all, [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and not [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). The two interfaces are related but distinct.

Now to your question. All that

```
Iterator it = ...;
```

really means is that `it` is a reference to **an instance of a class** implementing the `Iterator` interface. It's not a reference "to an interface" (such a thing would indeed not make a lot of sense since you can't instantiate an interface).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to make a test - something that makes no sense, but it works:

Comparable test = String.valueOf(1);

Comment: @RichardK: `String.valueOf(1)` returns an instance of a class implementing the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Yes, i tried to make something similar to my question, just to test if complilator or JVM will take as exception. It works.